# Number of console logs in component body not equal to number of rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component that is just supposed to console.log some dummy text when component is rendered. I have read some articles about rendering and I would assume that rendering happens at the same time as invoking the component, i.e. rendering is not possible without invoking/executing component function *a priori*.

So, the number of console logs in this case should be 2 for each - once when component initially renders, and second time when I click on the button and i is set to 2. Every next time React should be able to detect that state is actually not the same and not re-render the component.

But, I get "Hello from invoking" (that is not in use effect but in component body) three times, once when component initially renders, and two times when I click on the button. This component is for sure rendered just twice, so where did that third console.log come from? Is it possible that the component function is invoked, but not re-rendered? In contrary, "Hello from rendering" is logged twice as I would assume.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const DummyComponent = (props) => {
    const [i, setI] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("hello from rendering!");
    });

    console.log("hello from invoking!");

    return (
        <div onClick={() => setI(2)}}> Hello </div>
    );
};

export default DummyComponent;
```

Comment: Is this running in `React.StrictMode`? That often renders things more than people are expecting.

Comment: No. I have already disabled React.StrictMode.

Answer (score 0):

When the `onClick` calls `setI`, this causes a *change to the state* and an **update** gets triggered. This will call the lifecycle methods associated with [an update](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating).

> - static getDerivedStateFromProps()
> - shouldComponentUpdate()
> - render()
> - getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()
> - componentDidUpdate()

The [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is called during `componentDidUpdate()` (as well as `componentDidMount`), while the `console.log` outside the `useEffect` is going to be called during `render()`.

That means we should expect to see 1 `hello from rendering!` and 1 `hello from invoking!` when we refresh or when we click the "Hello" div.

In this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lifecycle-94sijb?file=/src/DummyComponent.jsx) you can see that we are getting the expected behavior of one a single `console.log` of each.

Now in this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lifecycle-strictmode-cgf79r?file=/src/index.js:202-260) we are using `StrictMode`, and you can see that when we click the "Hello", we are seeing `hello from rendering!` 1 time, but we are seeing `hello from invoking!` 2 times!

`StrictMode` was enabled by adding a `<StrictMode>` tag to `index.js`

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

It seems that the behavior you are describing is coming from the use of `StrictMode`.

This happens because `StrictMode` [intentionally double-invokes](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) the following functions:

> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Thus, we see the `render` function occurring 2 times, and we get the 2 `console.logs`.